# getting parse error when sourcing bash_profile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bash

I'm currently building rails app which has twitter, fb and instagram login options. I entered the right token and everything but when I do source bash_profile, it gives me this error

```
`(eval):1: parse error near `then' `
```

I'm guessing this part of my bash_profile is wrong?

```
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

but how could I fix this?

---

When I hit, ' rbenv init - '
I get the following

```
export PATH="/Users/sugawara/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=zsh
source '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec/../completions/rbenv.zsh'
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
  local command
  command="$1"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

 case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}
```

Comment: Please show the output of `rbenv init -`, after all, that's what caused the error.

Comment: @Socowi I added the answer to your question! Thx!

Comment: You are sourcing a `zsh` file from a `bash` script; that is probably the source of the error.

Comment: Are you really running this from bash? The output from `rbenv init -` on bash is completely different.

Answer (score 1):

RBenv integration for Bash looks like this:

```
export PATH="/Users/sugawara/.rbenv/shims:${PATH}"
export RBENV_SHELL=bash
source '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec/../completions/rbenv.bash'
command rbenv rehash 2>/dev/null
rbenv() {
  local command
  command="$1"
  if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then
    shift
  fi

  case "$command" in
  rehash|shell)
    eval "$(rbenv "sh-$command" "$@")";;
  *)
    command rbenv "$command" "$@";;
  esac
}
```

The only explaination I can think of for `rbenv init -` to output the instruction for the ZSH shell is that you may actually be running zsh instead of bash.

Comment: So he may have parse error in his `zsh` file `near then`?

Comment: Well thats the part that makes less sense @FabrizioBertoglio.

Answer (score 0):

my opinion, after reading the answer from [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/544825/max) is that you need to [follow the instructions](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout) to set up `rbenv` and in particular set up your `~/.zshrc` file instead of your `~.bash_profile`

> Add ~/.rbenv/bin to your $PATH for access to the rbenv command-line utility.

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshrc
```

> Ubuntu Desktop note: Modify your ~/.bashrc instead of ~/.bash_profile.
>   **Zsh note: Modify your ~/.zshrc file instead of ~/.bash_profile.**

as from your `rbenv init -` output we can see that:

```
export RBENV_SHELL=zsh
source '/usr/local/Cellar/rbenv/1.1.1/libexec/../completions/rbenv.zsh'
```

so probably you should set your `~/.zshrc` file instead of your `~/.bash_profile`